# Unable to open database file with using Cycript

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cycript

I am trying to attach Cycript to a running app on my jailbroken iPhone and I keep getting the following error:

```
*** _sqlcall(sqlite3_open_v2(db, &database_, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, NULL)):../Execute.cpp(2157):CYInitializeDynamic 14:unable to open database file
```

I am using an iPhone5 running iOS 10.3.3. Has anyone run into this or know how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem because I moved the Cycript script into /usr/bin and the libraries into /usr/lib so it wasn't finding the *.db files. I was running into other issues and realized that Cycript won't work because my phone is armv7 but Cycript is built for arm6. Oh well.